# Facebook comments and drupal user accounts

Tags: comments, social-network

Okay, so here is a very theoretical and community wiki like question:

I would like to have Facebook comments on my site but I need that anyone who has an account on my site gets referenced in the Facebook comment he/she posts.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or is this just not possible as Facebook comments are rendered in a iframe and are not at all related to my database?

Comment: Why is this a too broad question and should be closed? As of yet, there is not any full-fledged way to add comments to entities in Drupal 7. I think that Facebook comments is basically the only way around it and hence of interest to many people. Facebook comments is based on URLs only and hence can be used on any file entity page/user page/taxonomy page.

Comment: Your second sentence pretty much answers question you asked in first one, the way I see it. And there are at leas 3 modules to integrate with Facebook, each with own set of features and own documentation. But let's see how others will vote. From Drupal.org: "Found 1260 results containing the words: facebook comments" when searching modules.

Comment: The lack of an existing method to do something doesn't automatically make a question about it on-topic for a Stack Exchange site. I would probably agree with the close-voter that this is too broad

Comment: The closure description says it all: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format." No blame is put on who asked the question, but the question doesn't suit Stack Exchange's purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The various comment widgets Facebook provides are really just premade wrappers FB has created to keep a certain look and feel across the www.  If you want to create your own, you can certainly do so.  Broad documentation can be found on their [Developer Site](https://developers.facebook.com) with key documentation about creating comments here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-comments/#creating